# Changing Bootsrap slider to loop through pages instead of posts (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, slider

In my theme I added a bootstrap slider. To display the images in the slider I added a loop that goes through my posts and shows all posts with the category 'slider'. But instead of posts, I want all the featured images of pages with this tag to be displayed. (I already added the functionality of featured images and categories. Is there is a possibility to do this?

I tried adding the line `<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page')); ?>` but this didn't work.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <?php
        global $post;

        $query_args = array(
                'post_type'     => 'page',
                'posts_per_page' => '99',
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $page_query  = new WP_Query( $query_args );


           if ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++; ?>

            <?php if ($i==1) { ?>
                <div class="carousel-item active">
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="carousel-item">
            <?php } 

                 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); 
                ?>  
                <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url; ?>')"></div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div><!-- carousel-item active -->     

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from your query. You are using a prebuilt WordPress query called "query_posts()". The reason this is not pulling through the pages post type is because this query is specific to posts.

Try using the WP_Query with the same parameters.

```
global $post;

$query_args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => '99',
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$page_query  = new WP_Query( $query_args ); 

// then we start the loop using the query variable.

if ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I changed my code as you suggested. Unfortunately, the slider still displays the images of my posts (and not the pages) with the slider tag.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Apologies I did not see this comment.